# Where Is This Git Setting Coming From?

Tags: git, git-config

I am trying to find where each of these **credential.helper** values are set.

I listed all of my config and filtered on the value I was looking for and it looks like two conflicting values are being set. I want to keep the *timeout version* and remove the *keychain* version

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:tinker alexthomas$ git config --list |grep credential.helper
credential.helper=osxkeychain
credential.helper=cache --timeout=300
```

I looked in the global config and it was not there

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:tinker alexthomas$ git config --list --global |grep credential.helper
credential.helper=cache --timeout=300
```

I looked in the local config and it was not there

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:tinker alexthomas$ git config --list --local |grep credential.helper
```

The system config file does not even exist.

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:tinker alexthomas$ git config --list --system |grep credential.helper
fatal: unable to read config file '/etc/gitconfig': No such file or directory
```

So where is the *keychain* version coming from and how do I delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `git config -l --show-origin` to show where each setting is set.  The `osxkeychain` helper is enabled by default on Homebrew's Git, but can be disabled.  I don't know whether it ships enabled and if so, if it's possible to disable it, on Apple's Git.

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  I found the file where the keychain was being set and removed it.

A follow-up question:  The file that was the problem was: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/gitconfig  where is it confiedured to use this file?

Comment: You can compile Git to use any location you like for the system configuration.  Apple ships their Git with Xcode, so they've compiled it to look in one of the Xcode directories.  `/etc/gitconfig` is customary on Unix systems, but macOS isn't a typical Unix system.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation That is very frustrating.  The least Apple could have done is make --system point to the new file.